# Extjs 4 Load Array Data using Model

Tags: extjs

I feel like I may be over complicating this. Please feel free to send me in a different direction.

I'm trying to load an array of records (the values) with only values, into model objects, using the fields defined in my model (the keys).

My Model

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.AppData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'key'},
        {name: 'value'},
        {name: 'desc'},
        {name: 'index', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'type'}
    ]
});
```

My Store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.AppData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
    groupField: 'type',
    model: 'MyApp.model.AppData',
    autoload: false,
    constructor: function (config) {
        var data = [
            ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5'],
            ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5'],
            ...
        ];
    this.loadData(data);
    }
});
```

So the end goal here is to have my data in the store looking like

```
[
    {'key':'val1', 'value':'val2', 'desc':'val3', 'index':'val4', 'type':'val5'},
    {...},
    {...}
]
```

Currently getting a 'me.removed is undefined' error. I know its related to the loadData() function. Which makes me feel like I'm not using this correctly somewhere.

I could just hardcode the data formatted with the key value pairs... but that just feels unmaintainable and wrong way to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: That is what the array reader is for: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.5/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use store's data config:

```
var myModel=Ext.define('MyApp.model.AppData', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'key'},
        {name: 'value'},
        {name: 'desc'},
        {name: 'index', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'type'}
    ]
});

var myData = [
      ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 0, 'val5'],
      ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 1, 'val5']
];

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    model:myModel,
    data:myData
});
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15jd)

Comment: Perfect, and simple. Thanks Tony!